# Java ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor: Can Runnables in a List be executed after shutdownNow()?

Tags: java, threadpoolexecutor

I can't execute Runnables(delayed tasks in a queue), that have been returned in an list of Runnables after invoking of shutdownNow() on ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor object.

I've tried some ways to do it: you can get list size, one of the Runnable objects itself, invoke isDone() query, but I haven't coped to run them.

CAN they be executed and HOW if possible?

See please code below. Thank you.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.FutureTask;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;

public class ExecuteExisitingDelayedTasksAfterShutdownPolicy1 {
private static int count = 0;

private static class Task implements Runnable {
    private String name;

    public Task(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        count++;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return;
        }
        System.out.printf("\n%s: " + getName(), Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor stpe = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(10, new ThreadPoolExecutor.DiscardPolicy());
    stpe.setExecuteExistingDelayedTasksAfterShutdownPolicy(true);
    List<Runnable> queue = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        stpe.execute(new Task("Task " + count));
        if (i == 50) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            queue = stpe.shutdownNow();
            System.out.print("\nQueue SIZE: " + queue.size());
        }
    }
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    System.out.print("\n" + queue.get(0));
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    FutureTask<Task> ftask = (FutureTask<Task>) queue.get(0);
    ExecutorService ses = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    /**
     * all of the next.. doesn't work: tasks returned in a queue are likely 
    to be
     * unrunnable
     */
    ftask.get().run();
    System.out.println(ftask.get().name);
    ses.execute(ftask);
    queue.get(0).run();

   }
}
```

Comment: why? You usually `shutdown()` then `awaitTermination()` - what behavior are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes, but I would like to know, whether there is a possibility to run later these cancelled delayed tasks. Perhaps they can't be run anymore at all, or? That is, maximum information, we can about them after termination of executor - is their number, whether they are done and so on.

Comment: I tried to run these cancelled tasks

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"? What happens?

Comment: As I invoke:   ftask.get().run(), System.out.println(ftask.get().name), ses.execute(ftask), queue.get(0).run() - programm hangs, I become no output, but Terminate Button is red.

Comment: I see what you're trying and I see why it fails - The `List<Runnable>` returned by `shutdownNow()` is no more executable because your tasks are wrapped in `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask` which remember their cancelled status. When you execute them they just return and do nothing.  https://ideone.com/jtasx0 is a better example for that - Not sure if that's the intended behavior or a bad design choice by the Java framwork developers.

Comment: Thank you for good explanation